# pyqt4 crosshair does not follow mouse movement in GraphicsLayoutWidget. How do I effectively debug this?

Tags: python, pyqt4, pycharm, pyqtgraph

I have tried to reverse engineer the [MouseInteraction example](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/introduction.html) to add a crosshair to a `GraphicsLayoutWidget` of an already functioning app. Please consider reading my last paragraph as this is a problem I have stumbled upon before, yet I have yet to get the *broadly actionable* feedback I need.

Horizontal and vertical lines for the crosshair to be displayed is initialized as follows

```
class MultiRoiViewBox(pg.ViewBox):
    def __init__(self,parent=None,border=None,lockAspect=False,enableMouse=True,invertY=False,enableMenu=True,name=None):
        pg.ViewBox.__init__(self,parent,border,lockAspect,enableMouse,invertY,enableMenu,name)

        self.vLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=90, movable=False)
        self.hLine = pg.InfiniteLine(angle=0, movable=False)
        #Other initializations...
```

The cross-hair is only displayed after an image is loaded and displayed via the `GraphicsLayoutWidget`. When the following executes the image and crosshair are displayed, however the `SignalProxy` doesn't seem to establish the right connection since the crosshair does not follow the mouse.

```
def showImage(self,arr):
    if arr==None: 
        self.img = None
        return
    if self.img==None: 
        self.img = pg.ImageItem(arr,autoRange=False,autoLevels=False)
        self.addItem(self.img)
    self.addItem(self.vLine, ignoreBounds=True)
    self.addItem(self.hLine, ignoreBounds=True)
    proxy = pg.SignalProxy(self.scene().sigMouseMoved, rateLimit=60, slot=self.mouseMoved)
    self.img.setImage(arr,autoLevels=False)
    self.updateView()
```

Here is the function that is supposed to be called upon mouse movement.

```
def mouseMoved(self, ev):
    pos = ev[0]  ## using signal proxy turns original arguments into a tuple
    if self.sceneBoundingRect().contains(pos):
        mousePoint = self.vb.mapSceneToView(pos)
        index = int(mousePoint.x())
        self.vLine.setPos(mousePoint.x())
        self.hLine.setPos(mousePoint.y())
```

I have a breakpoint in the `mouseMoved` function and it is never triggered so the problem must lie in this single line in `showImage`:

```
proxy = pg.SignalProxy(self.scene().sigMouseMoved, rateLimit=60, slot=self.mouseMoved)
```

This even though there are no errors and I don't know what I should be looking for in the debugger since all the variables in this line of code seem to be in order. I can see that the scene is a `GraphicsScene`, but since [GraphicsLayoutWidget](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/widgets/graphicslayoutwidget.html) consists of a `GraphicsView` I assume all is in order

```
>>> pg
<module 'pyqtgraph' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyqtgraph/__init__.pyc'>
>>> self.scene()
<pyqtgraph.GraphicsScene.GraphicsScene.GraphicsScene object at 0x7f8aeb4ee640>
>>> self.scene().sigMouseMoved
<bound signal sigMouseMoved of GraphicsScene object at 0x7f8aeb4ee640>
>>> self.mouseMoved
<bound method MultiRoiViewBox.mouseMoved of <ViewBoxCustom.MultiRoiViewBox object at 0x7f8aeb4ee770>>
```

If you see the answer, I humbly request insight into how you arrived at it for my own improvement. It is unclear to me what the proper debugging steps should be in this case. I've identified the line that I'm sure must be causing the issue, with a breakpoint here I find everything seems to be in order so what am I, *generally speaking*, supposed to do in such a predicament?

I'm a pycharm pro user if that helps makes explanations easier.

Comment: Have you looked at the code here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17783428/how-to-draw-crosshair-and-plot-mouse-position-in-pyqtgraph which appears to do what you are trying to do? After setting up the proxy there is an additional line  `signalgraph.scene().sigMouseMoved.connect(mouseMoved)`

Comment: Ha! Yes that seems to do it. There was a line like that in the MouseIntersection example, but it causes an error so I assumed it was just a legacy-obsolete leftover. And yes I did indeed read that question (embarrassingly enough I looked at it quite thoroughly) and had wrongly convinced myself I was doing everything the same.

Answer (score 2):

You were right with your assumption in what line the problem is. You simply forgot that your `SignalProxy` has to be an instance object. In your code it is a local variable of `showImage`.

So adding a self. to the line with your definition of the SignalProxy should make your code work:

```
self.proxy = pg.SignalProxy(self.scene().sigMouseMoved, rateLimit=60, slot=self.mouseMoved)
```

Don't be ashamed. I once made the same mistake and needed a long time to see it. :D

To be clear because I read the suggestion from barny in the comments. Just adding `self.scene().sigMouseMoved.connect(self.mouseMoved)` is wrong! It will work because that is not using the `SignalProxy` at all. If you added this, you can remove the `SignalProxy` line and it will still work. If you correct your `SignalProxy` line you have to remove the line saying that again.

**I recommend using the `SignalProxy`**, because there you can use the option `rateLimit`. That is especially important in cases like yours when using `MouseMoved` or `MouseDrag events`. Otherwise dependend on how much code/how much calculation is done it can result in non-fluent movement like in your case the crosshair.

Hope that will help you or someone else.